# Can I use "as" instead of "which" in this case?

Tags: grammar

> When he was 30 years old, he bought another house, which (as) showed how adept he was in moneymaking.

In this sentence, "which" is referring back to its preceding sentence "when he was ~ another house", but is it grammatically correct to use "as" instead of "which" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, use "which" here.  "as" doesn't make sense.

"as" would work in these two cases:

He owned two houses when he was 30 years old, as he was adept in moneymaking.

As poor as he was, he was able to buy a house when he was 30 years old.